# phpseclib doesn't upload correct file contents

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

So what it does is successfully connects then uploads the file `logo.png` but the contents of the file isn't what was on web host or uploaded with html if i use a html upload code. What it puts in the file is the ACTUAL text between the second ' 's so for that very example the contents of logo.png is literally `logo.png` and not the picture.

```
require_once("ftp/vendor/autoload.php");

use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('SERVER');

if (!$sftp->login('USER', 'PW')) {
    throw new Exception('Login failed');
}

$sftp->put("/some/path/logo.png", "logo.png", NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would read through the documentation, you would find out that the second argument of the [`put()`](https://api.phpseclib.org/1.0/Net_SFTP.html#method_put) function is `$data`, therefore not the file path, but the actual data to write:

> `function put($remote_file, $data, $mode = NET_SFTP_STRING, $start = -1, $local_start = -1)`
>
> By default, `NetSFTP::put()` does not read from the local filesystem. `$data` is dumped directly into `$remotefile`. [...]

To upload a local file, the easiest way is to read the content into one variable that will be passed to the `put()` function:

```
$data = file_get_contents("logo.png");
$sftp->put("/some/path/logo.png", $data);
```

Edit: You are probably using a new version of phpseclib, which [renamed these constants](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L71) to make them more object-like. With a new version, you should use

```
$sftp->put("/some/path/logo.png", "logo.png", SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: But the `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE` mode overrides the default behavior. With `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE`, the `$data` argument is actually a path. So the OP's code is correct, while yours is actually wrong.

Comment: It can be that the OP version does not support this functionality.

Comment: Actually `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE` is supported ever since the phpseclib supports SFTP (2009): https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/d365b7a587afc7cb1712c4865fd48e9973a33f5d

Comment: Ok, you are right, but the current version renamed the constants so it will be the opposite -- too new version, reading old tutorials and ignoring php notices.